# Python: delete lines from XML file and create a new xml file

Tags: xml, parsing, python-3.6

I have an XML file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G0qtDY6HY9x7HQLY3vEmlba8cxLym5sw/view?usp=sharing

I want to delete lines with X="-3.276700000000E+04" and Y="-3.276700000000E+04". The block looks like this:

```
<GCPList Projection="GEOGCS[&quot;WGS 
84&quot;,DATUM[&quot;WGS_1984&quot;,SPHEROID[&quot;WGS 84&quot;,6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;7030&quot;]],AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;6326&quot;]],PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;,0,AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;8901&quot;]],UNIT[&quot;degree&quot;,0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;9122&quot;]],AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;4326&quot;]]">
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="0.5000" Line="0.5000" X="-8.887793731689E+01" Y="4.566011428833E+01" />
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="260.5000" Line="0.5000" X="-8.877786254883E+01" Y="4.566171646118E+01" />
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="520.5000" Line="0.5000" X="-8.867778015137E+01" Y="4.566323089600E+01" />...
<GCP Id="" Pixel="3640.5000" Line="7347.5000" X="-3.276700000000E+04" Y="-3.276700000000E+04" />
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="3900.5000" Line="7347.5000" X="-3.276700000000E+04" Y="-3.276700000000E+04" />
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="4160.5000" Line="7347.5000" X="-3.276700000000E+04" Y="-3.276700000000E+04" />
    <GCP Id="" Pixel="4420.5000" Line="7347.5000" X="-3.276700000000E+04" Y="-3.276700000000E+04" />
</GCPList>
```

I want to delete these lines of code and update the file.

The code that I have written is:

```
file = ET.parse('input6.vrt')
root = file.getroot()
for item in root.findall('.//trigger/GCPList'):
    check_req_elems = elem.find('./@X=-32767]' and './@Y=-32767')
    check_elem = elem.find('./@X=-32767]' and './@Y=-32767')
    if check_req_elems is not None and check_elem is not None:
            elem.remove(check_elem)
```

However, this does not seem to make any changes to the file.